# Python Selenium Scrape with dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using python and selenium to scrape a website.  However I am having issues selecting an element from a dropdown list.  When I run this script on windows in the python IDE I can get my script to work:

```
listElement = driver.find_element_by_id('header-transactionTypeOptions')
transElement = driver.find_element_by_id('container-primary-4-transactionTypeOptions')
listElement.click()
time.sleep(2)
transElement.click()

<input id="header-transactionTypeOptions" class="jpui input header focus-on-header wrap right text-float-left   " type="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label=" SHOWING:: Activity since last statement" value="Activity since last statement">
```

However, when I run this on my ubuntu instance with pyvirtualdisplay it tells me it cannot locate the element.  In my research for using selenium with a drop down - the suggested answers are using "Select".  However there is no "Select ID" on the elements on this webpage.

I have include the elements below, as other options to reference in trying to find an answer:

```
<button id="iconButton-transactionTypeOptions" type="button" class="jpui input-icon icon text-overflow" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><span class="jpui expanddown icon input-icon hasError"></span></button>

<span class="primary" id="container-primary-1-transactionTypeOptions">Jul 21, 2016 statement </span>
```

Comment: might want to wait for the element to be visible

Comment: The element loads when the webpage loads.  So it's visible.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: its www.chase.com - probably not helpful though as you would need a log in

Comment: Are you using different browsers in the different operating systems?  I know when I've written Selenium scripts for testing web apps before there are certain discrepancies between using Firefox and Chrome and even between Chrome on Ubuntu (not chromium) and Chrome on Windows.

Comment: No, its chrome/chromedriver on both systems

Comment: Might be a dumb question on my end but in the first code block you have `container-primary-4` but in the second code block you have `container-primary-1`.  Are they supposed to be different?